# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64,1) into shape (10,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I get said error in line 5 when running this code:

```
                elif backward_pass[j].type == "L":
                    backward_pass[j].change_w = np.multiply(backward_pass[j + 1].out[i].T, error[i, j, :, :])  # vector is tipped so multiplication returns a matrix; has to be tipped anti-clock-wise
                    backward_pass[j].change_b = 1 * error[i, j, :, :]
                    print(backward_pass[j].grad.T.shape)
                    error[i, j + 1, :, :] = np.dot(backward_pass[j].grad.T, error[i, j, :, :])
```

error[...] has shape (10, 1). For the first argument's shape, the print command returns

```
(64, 10)
```

as it is supposed to be. However, np.dot sets the last axis to 1. Even when using a custom function to replace np.dot, the same problem occurs.

Help.

Comment: Check your indexing for this "error[i, j + 1, :, :]", because the arrays are getting multiplied that's why the input array is of (64, 1) as shown in the error but it cannot be broadcasted.

Comment: Thanks! The indexing was indeed the problem.